# Initialize object while debugging in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Just wondering if there is anyway to initialize an object to its default value when debugging in visual studio.

For null strings etc you can just set them but i dont know how to do this for a compex type.

Comment: `obj = new YourClassName();` maybe?

Comment: @dotNET I said while debugging.

Comment: Yeah. You can run that in QuickWatch or Immediate windows.

Comment: @dotNET Ah cool. I havent really used to the immediate window before.

Comment: Great. I'll post some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run valid C# statements during a debug session using **QuickWatch** or **Immediate** windows (among other ways). Just set a breakpoint at the statement where you'd like to do this and then when the code hits that breakpoint, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up QuickWatch or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> for Immediate window (depending upon your environment settings, your keys may be different). Therein, you can run the following line to assign a new instance of your class to your variable:

```
obj = new YourClassName();
```

This will assign a new instance of your class to `obj` with default values set and the code can continue from that point onward.

While your code has hit a breakpoint and is in **Break** mode, You can also make changes directly into the code. These changes will take effect immediately and you can continue execution from that point onward. This feature is known as **Edit and Continue**.

Note that there are several caveats related to what can and can't be done through QuickWatch or Immediate windows. There are some types of code changes that can be tolerated by the IDE and the output adjusted accordingly on-the-fly, and there are other types of changes that will require you to restart your debug session. For example, assigning a new value to a variable will be tolerated, whereas defining a new function will not be.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the default keyword in the framework e.g

`var obj=default(YourClass);`

The above will by default be a null.